# sending mail from linux commad line

Tags: linux, command-line, email, sendmail, mailx

Is it possible to send mail from linux terminal to any gmail account.

If possible then what are the configuration are needed.

I tried with mailx and sendmail but its not working.

I also tried with mutt like this

`echo "test" | mutt -s this-is-my-subjest XXXXX@gmail.com`

but no use...

I am using CentOS 6.2

Comment: What is not working? Do you get an error message? Have you checked any log files?

Comment: I am not getting any error msg. but not getting mail also.

Comment: You should be able to find a log file in `/var/log/`. It is often called `maillog` or similar. What does it say after you try your command?

Comment: nothing, next command prompt will appear.

Comment: in var/log/maillog its showing `Network is unreachable`

Comment: Pulling from a file is effective: `echo "email from serverX" > ~/testemail`; then:
`mail -s 'another test subject' youremail@gmail.com < ~/testemail`

Answer (score 4):

I would advise to use sendEmail:

```
sendEmail-1.56 by Brandon Zehm <caspian@dotconf.net>

Synopsis:  sendEmail -f ADDRESS [options]

  Required:
    -f ADDRESS                from (sender) email address
    * At least one recipient required via -t, -cc, or -bcc
    * Message body required via -m, STDIN, or -o message-file=FILE

  Common:
    -t ADDRESS [ADDR ...]     to email address(es)
    -u SUBJECT                message subject
    -m MESSAGE                message body
    -s SERVER[:PORT]          smtp mail relay, default is localhost:25

  Optional:
    -a   FILE [FILE ...]      file attachment(s)
    -cc  ADDRESS [ADDR ...]   cc  email address(es)
    -bcc ADDRESS [ADDR ...]   bcc email address(es)
    -xu  USERNAME             username for SMTP authentication
    -xp  PASSWORD             password for SMTP authentication

  Paranormal:
    -b BINDADDR[:PORT]        local host bind address
    -l LOGFILE                log to the specified file
    -v                        verbosity, use multiple times for greater effect
    -q                        be quiet (i.e. no STDOUT output)
    -o NAME=VALUE             advanced options, for details try: --help misc
        -o message-content-type=<auto|text|html>
        -o message-file=FILE         -o message-format=raw
        -o message-header=HEADER     -o message-charset=CHARSET
        -o reply-to=ADDRESS          -o timeout=SECONDS
        -o username=USERNAME         -o password=PASSWORD
        -o tls=<auto|yes|no>         -o fqdn=FQDN


  Help:
    --help                    the helpful overview you're reading now
    --help addressing         explain addressing and related options
    --help message            explain message body input and related options
    --help networking         explain -s, -b, etc
    --help output             explain logging and other output options
    --help misc               explain -o options, TLS, SMTP auth, and more
```

It works very well for me. 
Remember to use TLS with gmail.
You need to provide details of the server that will send the email with those options:

```
    -s SERVER[:PORT]          smtp mail relay, default is localhost:25
    -xu  USERNAME             username for SMTP authentication
    -xp  PASSWORD             password for SMTP authentication
```

It's best for me as it allows to add attachments and can be easily placed in the scripts.

Example usage:

```
sendEmail -f x1user@gmail.com -t x2user@gmail.com -s test -m messageBody -s smtp.gmail.com -xu x1user@gmail.com -xp xxxxxpass -o tls=auto
Aug 17 16:21:37 z sendEmail[22420]: Email was sent successfully!
```

Comment: can u provide one simple example?

Comment: sure i will place it in the answer at the bottom

Comment: sendmail can do much more thing that mailto, but I found it's use rather complicated, I use sendmail in alertscript to get everything, but to just send a mail, mailto is rather simple I think. Like using a rifle to shoot a mosquito for me.

Comment: possibly. but what you probably missed - i'm proposing send-`E`-mail. not sendmail. i've never had a chance to use sendmail but sendEmail does everything i need.

Comment: no sendEmail command installed, so I tried `yum install sendEmail` but its giving `No package sendEmail available`

Comment: download link : http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/sendEmail-v1.56.tar.gz
unzip it, then ./configure ./make ./make install

Answer (score 3):

The `mail` terminal program should do the trick.  It usually works "straight out of the box" to allow users/programs to send messages locally, inside the system.

Type `mail -s 'subject line' someone@gmail.com` and hit return.  Then type your message and close/send using Ctl-D.

Comment: I tried this but not working... any configuration are needed, before doing this?

Comment: Can you try sending an email to yourself on the machine: `mail -d -s subject your name@localhost`.  The -d option will provide debugging output to tell you what is causing the problem.

Comment: On some systems you have to use mailx instead of mail.

Answer (score 0):

normally you don't have to any specific configuration, centos got by default a mail server.

If i recall the command is `mailto` then type the information (from, subject etc,...) and type your text, and when you've finished typing type ctrl+D, you'll get EOT.

Be aware that you mail server will use your user information, something like that `from : user@pcname` but I'm not on my linux today so I can't check that.

Hope this will help.

**EDIT :**

there the link to O'reilly man page : [there](http://www.oreillynet.com/linux/cmd/cmd.csp?path=m/mailto)