# How to hide password while sending mail from linux commad line

Tags: linux, email, passwords, history

I tried the approach in https://superuser.com/a/462871 and it works. But I don't want my gmail password to be stored in command history. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a Bash shell then try adding a space to the beginning of the command you enter.

If that does not work then add [ \t]* to HISTIGNORE.